# PHP member reset password form not submitting (yes me again)

Tags: php

Hi again this is me nearly done with the gubbings of the site but im scratching my head to why this reset password page does not go through any of it procedures. Im sure it is again something minor but i cant see it, seems as though my reset button is not working at all but its the correct spelling when i call it and all the brackets as far as i can tell are correct. im sure the more i get used to these errors the more ill catch them myself. apologies for the dumb question.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Member system : Forgot password</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!$username && !$userid) {

    if($_POST['resetbtn']) {
        //get form data
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        //make sure info provided
        if($user) {
            if($email) {
                if((strlen($email) > 7) && (strstr($email, "@")) &&    (strstr($email, ".")) ) {
                    require("./connect.php");

                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE   username='$user'");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if($numrows == 1) {
                        // info about account
                        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                        $dbemail = $row['email'];

                        //make sure email is correct
                        if($email == $dbemail) {
                            // generate a password
                            $pass = rand();
                            $pass = md5($pass);
                            $pass = substr($pass, 0, 15);
                            $password =   md5(md5("12345".$pass."54321"));

                            //update db with new pass
                            mysql_query("UPDATE user SET  password='$password' WHERE username='$user'");

                            //make sure password was changed
                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$password'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if($numrows == 1) {
                                //create our email variables
                                $webmaster =  "mwilkins877@gmail.com";
                                $headers = "From:  Mike<$webmaster>";
                                $subject = "Your new password";
                                $message = "Your password has been reset, your new password is below. \n";
                                $message .= "Password: $pass\n";

                                echo $pass."<br/>";
                                if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                    echo "Your password has been reset an email has been sent with your new password";
                                }
                                else
                                    echo "An error has occured and your email wasnt sent containing your new password";
                            }
                            else
                                echo "An error has occured and the password was not set";
                        }
                        else
                            echo "You have entered the wrong email address";

                    }
                    else 
                        echo "The user name was not found";

                    mysql_close();
                }
                else "Please enter a valid email address";
            }
            else
                echo "please enter your email";
        }
        else
            echo "Please enter your user name";
    }
    else
        echo"<from action='./forgotpass.php' method='post'>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>email</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='resetbtn' value='Reset password'/>  </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";
}
else
    echo "Please log out to view this page";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate your help on this as its only just me learning for fun. Look forward to hearing back of some one hopefully. thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you check if username & userid exists not if it does not exist?  if(!$username && !$userid) { change to if($username && $userid) {

Comment: Your code is **open to SQL injection**. Switch to PDO or MySQLi *immediately*. Also I hope you are both hashing your passwords and not doing it with MD5.

Comment: It's okay that you're learning but you could definitively put more effort into your questions. You dump your complete code here and basically say "it doesn't work". Find out what part isn't working and explain how it fails to do so.

Comment: Sorry for wording the question poorly. Thanks for your responses. I will take on board what you say as i dont want to come across lazy. ill switch to myqli thanks for your adivse and while check both User and ID now which makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: Only switching to MySQLi won't solve the sql injection problem without changing his query.

Answer (score 5):

please correct the spelling  of the form

```
echo"<from action='./forgotpass.php' method='post'>
```

to

```
echo"<form action='./forgotpass.php' method='post'>
```

Hope this will fix your issue

Comment: Great, dont i look stupid! im not sure if being dyslexic hinders me but for the life of me i looked at that form for ages and even when you posted that i couldnt tell the difference lol how embarassing. Thank you for your help the members on here are great.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. Its working for me.

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<body>
<?php
if(!$username && !$userid) {

    if($_POST['resetbtn']) {
        //get form data
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        //make sure info provided
        if($user) {
            if($email) {
                if((strlen($email) > 7) && (strstr($email, "@")) &&    (strstr($email, ".")) ) {
                    require("./connect.php");

                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE   username='$user'");
                    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                    if($numrows == 1) {
                        // info about account
                        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                        $dbemail = $row['email'];

                        //make sure email is correct
                        if($email == $dbemail) {
                            // generate a password
                            $pass = rand();
                            $pass = md5($pass);
                            $pass = substr($pass, 0, 15);
                            $password =   md5(md5("12345".$pass."54321"));

                            //update db with new pass
                            mysql_query("UPDATE user SET  password='$password' WHERE username='$user'");

                            //make sure password was changed
                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  user WHERE username='$user' AND password='$password'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if($numrows == 1) {
                                //create our email variables
                                $webmaster =  "mwilkins877@gmail.com";
                                $headers = "From:  Mike<$webmaster>";
                                $subject = "Your new password";
                                $message = "Your password has been reset, your new password is below. \n";
                                $message .= "Password: $pass\n";

                                echo $pass."<br/>";
                                if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                                    echo "Your password has been reset an email has been sent with your new password";
                                }
                                else
                                    echo "An error has occured and your email wasnt sent containing your new password";
                            }
                            else
                                echo "An error has occured and the password was not set";
                        }
                        else
                            echo "You have entered the wrong email address";

                    }
                    else 
                        echo "The user name was not found";

                    mysql_close();
                }
                else "Please enter a valid email address";
            }
            else
                echo "please enter your email";
        }
        else
            echo "Please enter your user name";
    }
    else
        echo"<form action='./forgotpass.php' method='post'>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>email</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='email'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='resetbtn' value='Reset password'/>  </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";
```

Comment: Thanks i have it working now just need to make it pretty. Thanks for your response.